# apache htaccess redirect http to https for domain calls, but not for ajax

Tags: ajax, apache, .htaccess, redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am switching my web/ios/android app to https. I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk and an .ebextension configuration. In order to automatically redirect users who type the non https address, I have the following rewrite rule:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd_redirect.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
      RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME} [L,R=301]
```

The problem is I want to keep backwards compatibility with our current iOS and Android apps, which still make http ajax calls.

How do I redirect http to https for anyone who types the url, but not for the ajax calls?

Thanks!

As per War10ck's comment, I tried adding the following to make it skip over AJAX requests

```
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
```

but that did not work either:

```
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/https_redirect.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
      RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
      RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME} [L,R=301]
```

The error I am getting when trying to connect using an iOS app using PhoneGap to the server is:

```
  [Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/get_userinfo.php?&session_id=ca913df1d110b330ed405d524b0695b2. Origin http://localhost:12344 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Everything works and there are no errors if I remove the http to https redirect.

Comment: You'll probably want to look for the `X-Requested-With` header though admittedly I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but didn't work, assuming I used it correctly.